# PHP Write/Read file on VPN folder

Tags: php, vpn

My office have shared folder on \\172.168.x.xx (Local Ethernet)

If I want to access to folder on that from my home. I can use by set VPN on my OS with username password and Host (I use host of ddns of noip.com)

Now I develop website and user want read and write file from my website that file is on \\172.168.x.xx

Can I use PHP that read file on that vpn with username + password + host ?

Directory Such as \\172.168.x.xx\folder\abc.txt

I don't have idea for it. Thank for any help. Sorry for my bad grammar in English Language.

Comment: Is the web server on your computer? PHP doesn't care about the VPN, it's a network layer below it, As long as it can access it through your computer (which is connected to the VPN) then that's all that matters.

Comment: No web server is on cloud.